# How to tell what version of Instance Metadata Service(IMDS) EC2 instance is using?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to figure out what version of Instance Metadata Service my ec2 instance is using.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html#configuring-instance-metadata-options

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to determine it from the EC2 instance, you can just try sending a request to http://169.254.169.254/ and see what the status code is.

For example, this instance has IMDSv2 enabled and requests without a token are not accepted:

```
$ curl -w "%{http_code}\n" http://169.254.169.254/
401
```

The [401](https://httpstatuses.com/401) status code means Unauthorized.

If you have AWS access keys with permissions to describe EC2 instances, then you can run the following:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --instance-id i-0123456789abcdef --query "Reservations[0].Instances[0].MetadataOptions"
{
    "State": "applied",
    "HttpTokens": "optional",
    "HttpPutResponseHopLimit": 1,
    "HttpEndpoint": "enabled"
}
```

This server does not require IMDSv2 (`HttpTokens` is `optional`).

To enable IMDSv2, you can run `aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options`. See more in [AWS documentation on configuring the instance metadata options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-options.html).

Comment: Just to add use AWD Config Rule - [ec2-imdsv2-check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/ec2-imdsv2-check.html) to automate the check for EC2 compliance.

Answer (score 6):

Let me summarise what I found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)

1. Connect to an instance via the EC2 service in the AWS Console
2. Put the IMDSv1 command: `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/`
3. If you receive a list items then your instance can use IMDSv1 requests. If you receive `401 - Unauthorized` then it uses IMDSv2 or non.
4. Now put the IMDSv2 command: `TOKEN=curl -X PUT "<http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token"> -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600" && curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/`
5. If you receive a list of items, then your instance can use IMDSv2 requests. Otherwise, your instance is not allowed to request meta data at all (regardless of the version)

If you want to change this configuration [follow this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-metadata-options.html).

Comment: Stack overflow formatting removed the backticks from #4.

Answer (score 2):

Run these two commands:

If this works, you have IMDSv1

```bash
[ec2-user ~]$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

If this works, you have IMDSv2:

```bash
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` \
&& curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

Comment: good to know! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to get IP address of the EC2 host from ECS container, you can use the following simple bash script:

```
#Check IMDSv1 or IMDSv2 is being used on the instance
status_code=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/)
if [[ "$status_code" -eq 200 ]]
then
  export CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)"
else
  export CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="$(TOKEN=`curl -s -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` && curl -s -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)"
fi
```